# $K[\alpha]=K(\alpha)$ (if and) only if $\alpha$ is algebraic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, field-theory, extension-field

I think I have totally confused myself and just wanted to check whether the only if in the statement above even holds. Let us look at some field extension $K/L$ and some $\alpha\in L$. We proved in the lecture that if $\alpha$ is algebraic, then $L=K(\alpha)$ as a simple extension generated by an algebraic element will be algebraic. In particular, $K(\alpha)=K[\alpha]$, where $K(\alpha)$ denotes the smallest field containing both $K$ and $\alpha$ and $K[\alpha]$ is the image of the evaluation homomorphism.

But, the other direction should also hold, shouldn't it. We denote $\phi_\alpha: K[X]\rightarrow L, f\mapsto f(\alpha)$ as the evaluation homomorphism. Suppose now the field $L$ is generated as a $K$-algebra of a single element $\alpha\in L$ (and $\notin K$, otherwise the statement would be pointless). Then, by definition of $K-$algebras, $L=K[\alpha]=$im$(\phi_\alpha)$. Since, in general $K[\alpha]\subset K(\alpha)$ but here $K[\alpha]$ is already a field it holds $K[\alpha]=K(\alpha)$.

Now, comes my question. I think that this already suffices to conclude that $L$ must be algebraic. It suffices to show that $\alpha$ is algebraic. My "proof": Since $K[\alpha]$ is a field there is some $f\in K[X]$ with $\deg(f)\geq1$ such that $\alpha^{-1}=\phi_a(f)$. Since $\phi_\alpha$ is a homomorphism, $\phi_\alpha(X*f-1)=\alpha*\alpha^{-1}-1=0$ but, since $K[X]$ is an integral domain $\deg(fX-1)=\deg(X)+\deg(f)\geq 2$. Which means $\ker(\phi_\alpha)$ is non-trivial and, thus, $\alpha$ must be algebraic.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: The other direction is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3985501/k-alpha-is-a-field-implies-alpha-is-algebraic). Have a look.

Comment: Oh well, did not see that. I am very sorry but thank you!

Comment: Basic* questions like these have been asked a lot of times here, and you can find them easily with the search function. In this case, they were even automatically suggested in the "related" section next to this question (and upon creation, these related questions are displayed as well). I found 2 others. So please use the search function next time. *I am not saying that this question must be easy for you when you first learn it. I mean "basic" in the sense that every person learning the relevant field will stumble upon this problem / lemma and that it is explained in many books on the subject.